# Adjust Scrollbar height and width in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

How to adjust Scrollbar height and width.

```
Scrollbar(
    child: ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      children: [
        const Text(
          'Red Hat Installation in VirtualBox',
          style: darktext2,
        ),
        ] ), )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `thickness`,

```dart
Scrollbar(
  thickness: 33, //this
  child: ListView(
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more on [api.flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html)

Comment: This only helps to change the width (thickness). How can we use the fixed height scrollbar handle?

Comment: @RaghuMudem try to wrap with SizedBox, if fails it will be easier if you create new question.